# AS2 Final Fantasy type Inventory

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2, inventory

Edit: since I wasn't clear originally, I'm having trouble working out an AS2 inventory with stacking consumables and equippable weapons/armor, my code below is the arrays holding the values I've been working on for years but haven't figured any viable way to make work. I'm looking for help/ideas of how I can make an array hold these values and make them stack

Since about 2008, I've been working on a flash RPG. While I'm making headway, my biggest roadblock is the lack of item system which is becoming increasingly hard to create in AS2 as all of the great coders are slowly refusing to touch flash anymore. It's far too late to start over in a different language, my main file is a well over 500mb .fla

Honestly, I'd pay whoever can figure this out cause this game has a few other issues I'd like help with after this is solved. I'll throw down $50 usd to whoever can make a good item system with these reqs

- Has to be able to draw from a database of different item types (consumable, weapon, armor, accessory)
- Consumables must be able to "stack" (weapons, armor, accessories dont need to stack)

  Consumables must be able to directly affect hp/mp values (heal and the like)

  Weapons Armour acc. must have values attached to them so they can affect the character's stats when equipped (ex.strength +10 or something)

  Items must be able to be bought and sold

  Items must be able to be displayed in text (movieclips of each item is not really necessary)

  AS2

  Pretty much this below : (***Final Fantasy*** item/inventory example)

[image]

File size is not an issue whatsoever, these items must be able to be rendered in game

Literally if possible, use Final Fantasy 7 (or any FF game) as a basis for how the item system should work. If you can get it close to that, I'll pay you immediately. This is the code I was working on...

```
//ITEM SYSTEM
//this array will hold all items, inside of it, hopefully to be called inside of itself

//0.......1............2........3......4.... array element values
//name, description, effect, price, item type
_global.itemlist = [
//CONSUMABLES
["Sweetroot", "Restores 50 HP", 50, 100, "consumable"],
["Sugarroot", "Restores 100 HP", 100, 500, "consumable"],
["Candyroot", "Fully restores HP", 9999, 5000, "consumable"],
["Bitterroot", "Restores 50 MP", 50, 200, "consumable"],
["Sourroot", "Restores 100 MP", 100, 600, "consumable"],
["Tartroot", "Fully restores MP", 9999, 10000, "consumable"]
];
//0.......1............2....3....4...5....6.....7. array element values
//name, description, user, str, sta, def, mst, item type
_global.weaponlist = [
//WEAPONS
["Secred", "A mysterious zanbato with seals on the blade", "azul", 50, 0, 25, 10, "weapon"],
["Illuminite", "A thin weapon with a diamond rod for focusing light", "aseru", 50, 10, 10, 50, "weapon"],
["Fists", "A bare handed attack", "malforn", 50, 0, 55, 0, "weapon"],
["Kazeshini", "An oddly shaped blade for quick attacks ", "vayle", 20, 10, 25, 10, "weapon"],
["Yamato", "A katana with a blue hilt and a lightweight blade", "aoizi", 50, 20, 35, 50, "weapon"],
["Saleria", "A heavy scythe made from chenre absorbing crystal", "laava", 50, 20, 35, 50, "weapon"]
];
//0.......1............2....3....4...5....6...7 array element values
//name, description, str, sta, def, mst, price, item type
_global.armorlist = [
["Clothes", "light clothing", 0, 10, 10, 0, 500, "armor"],
["Armor", "plated armor", 0, 20, 20, 0, 5000,"armor"],
["Chain", "a thick chain for attack or defense", 20, 10, 10, 0, 500,"armor"],
["Shawl", "thin fabric worn by women", 0, 0, 5, 10, 7000,"armor"],
["Bodysuit", "a thick full body suit", 10, 20, 20, 0, 7500,"armor"],
["Spiked Araments", "armor covered in spikes, increases attack strength", 30, 0, 20, 0, 8000,"armor"]

];

//0.......1............2....3....4...5....6...7 array element values
//name, description, str, sta, def, mst, price, item type
_global.acclist = [
["Blade Ring", "raises attack", 30, 0, 0, 0, 500,"accesory"],
["Vigor Ring", "raises stamina", 0, 30, 0, 0, 500,"accesory"],
["Shield Ring", "raises defense", 0, 0, 30, 0, 500,"accesory"],
["Chenre Ring", "raises mental", 0, 0, 0, 30, 500,"accesory"],
["Knife Ring", "greatly raises attack", 120, 0, 0, 0, 50000,"accesory"],
["Vehemence Ring", "greatly raises stamina", 0, 120, 0, 0, 50000,"accesory"],
["Aegis Ring", "greatly raises defense", 0, 0, 120, 0, 50000,"accesory"],
["Aura Ring", "greatly raises mental", 0, 0, 0, 120, 50000,"accesory"]
];
```

- get item **Name** with `item[0][0];`
- get item **Description** with `item[0][1];`
- get item **Effect** with `item[0][2];`
- Example : If item[0] is being addressed then... (`item[0] [0]` =
  Secred (*as Name*). Then `item[0] [1]` = Fists (*as Description*), and so on. `trace(item[0][4]);` should trace the name **Sweetroot**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is not a project outsourcing site.

Comment: Can you not? I'm not outsourcing anything, I need help and I'm offering money as an incentive. If anyone wants to help for free, they're more than welcome. It's not like I'm making money off of this, I've been soloing this project for years. I legit can't think of any way to make the kind of item system I'm aiming for. if I was outsourcing my project, I would have linked you directly to my .fla

Comment: As you admit yourself it's "**_becoming increasingly hard to create in AS2_**" so maybe move onto **AS3** which makes coding things much easier (more powerful, more flexible, more command options... etc). You'll have to learn AS3 in a few weeks and then just port your code. It'll be easier than re-writing your code in Java or C#. If you tried AS3 for a couple of weeks you wouldn't need that Flashkit thread post from 2014.

Comment: So instead of finishing this one final aspect of the game, learn and rewrite 8 years of work in a different language. Yeah, no.

Comment: I'd suggest creating an `Item` class and extend it for consumables etc. And another class for handling the whole inventory (sort, stack, consume, put on etc). AS2 does support object-oriented programming more than it seems